# How to ensure the stability of a pc?

Tags: crash, cpu, scientific-computing

I need to run an intensive CPU task that maxes all cores of my CPU to 100%.

After a few days of running this task, I find that the machine becomes unresponsive and I am no longer able to SSH into it. I then have to restart the machine and begin the task again. This task could take several weeks or even months to compute.

I'd like to find a way to run this task to completion.

I've tried running the task on Debian 8 and Ubuntu Server LTS. Both of these operating system exhibited the same problem. I thought about running the task inside a Virtual Machine and using Cron to snapshot it every hour, but this seems quite extreme and would suffer an overhead.

Why is it that my machine is unstable?

Could it be due to power fluctuations?

Should I try under-clocking the CPU?

Thanks

Comment: Did you write that process? Maybe it leaks memory or otherwise consumes all resources of the PC. If it was just the 100% CPU usage, you'd have problems right away. But to be sure, you could give the threads of the process lower priority. That way, it will still consume 100% CPU if possible, but it will be at the end of the queue when you want to do something else, like logging in using SSH. Of course there may be physical problems too, like the CPU getting too hot, but there is no way to tell from here, and it that case it would be off-topic, I guess.

Comment: I didn't write the process. It's a Boolean Satisfiability Solver called Lingeling[1]. I've monitored memory usage and it seems to scale to what's available on the system, but maybe it's doing something dangerous? [1] http://fmv.jku.at/lingeling/